# how to display the contributors of a Github repository

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in HTML CSS and js and I am trying to list out the contributors of a repository in Github
I have collected the JSON object using the API

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repository-contributors

but I don't know how can I list out all of them using HTML  in a div

Take a look at my js file:

```js
const getUsers = () => {
    axios
        .get(
            "https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors "
        )
        .then((response) => {
            const users = response.data;
            console.log(users);
            const h1 = document.querySelector(".name");
            h1.innerHTML = `${users[1].login}`;
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
};
getUsers();
```

and here is an example of how my data object looks like:

```js
[
{
    "login": "bugron",
    "id": 13225220,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjEzMjI1MjIw",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/13225220?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/bugron",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/bugron",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/bugron/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/bugron/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/bugron/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/bugron/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/bugron/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/bugron/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/bugron/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/bugron/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/bugron/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false,
    "contributions": 297
}
]
```

I want to get the login value and display them in different divs

Comment: What does `users` look like?

Comment: @ksav here you go https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1rXU.png I want to get the value of login of the user

Comment: Please add a sample of it as text to your question. Don't post _images_ of code, text, errors etc. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#map` and extract all `login` and using `array#join`, you can join these `login`.

```js
const getUsers = () => {
    const owner = 'fabpot',
          repo = 'symfony';
    axios
        .get(
            `https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/contributors`
        )
        .then((response) => {
            const users = response.data;
            const div = document.querySelector(".name");
            div.innerHTML = users.map(u => u.login).join('<br />');
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
};
getUsers();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
<div class="name"></div>
```